# Difference between Turing machine end state and halt

Tags: terminology, turing-machines

Is there a difference between the end state of a Turing machine and the halt state? Especially, for example the Busy Beaver 3. It is said that it is with 3 states but there is also a halt. Is the end state $q_2$ or the $halt$?

Comment: *Busy Beaver* is a famous Turing machine problem, which aims of determining the maximum number of steps, done by a TM, when computing the number of 1s starting from an empty tape. For one 1 (one state) - one step, for four 1s (2 states) - six steps, for six 1s (3 states) - fourteen steps. So it grows exponentially. Therefore, it is proved that it`s not computable. The problem however, dates back from 1960s.

Comment: The growth is not exponential, it is super-exponential. Also, exponential growth (and even super-exponential growth) doesn't imply non-computable. However it happens to be the case that the busy beaver function growths faster than every computable function.

Answer (score 2):

"End(ing) state" and "halt(ing) state" are just two (four) different ways of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

In the specific case of the Busy Beaver , the end state is the halt state, al other states (q0,q1,q2) must have a transition defined for every symbol in the alphabet of the TM so the machine doesn't halt on them.

Comment: Also, considering the definition of the busy beaver problem, the halting state is not considered a "regular" state, probably because it is not optional. I believe you are making the common mistake of thinking that the state with the higher index ($q_2$, in your example) has some special attribute, but it doesn't.